# Angular 2+ dynamically generate css

Tags: css, angular, interpolation, ng-style

For a given js variable, which has style information in it:

```
menuBgColor = "red";
```

In AngularJS I was able to use dynamically embedded style:

```
<div>
   <style>
      .menuElement{
         background-color:{{menuBgColor}}
      }
   </style>
   <div class="menuElement">...</div>
</div>
```

In Angular2+ I cannot use the same as above. When the view is rendered in the browser variable `menuBgColor` is not populated and the  element is rendered as coded.

like this -

```
<body>
...other markup...
<div><style>.menuElement{background-color:{{menuBgColor}}}</style>
...markup...
</body>
```

I want to know that what are the other ways in angular 2+ to add dynamic styles to the view?

- I know of ngStyle but the given example is a very small one.
- In my case, I have to apply dynamic styles to each element of the whole app like button, borders, background, colors, tree controls,
  sidebars etc. So ngStyle is very exhaustive.
- I also do not have predefined theme files because theme is managed by a feature in our app where user can define his/her own theme. Here
  I understand that I can refresh page to get the updated theme BUT
  consider that there can be 'n' number of users with their own themes.
- So in my use case, the only solution I can think of is that somehow variable interpolate and create an embedded css.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it `menuBgColor` or `menu.bgColor`?

Comment: Corrected, it is `menuBgColor`

Comment: What about CSS preprocessors like SASS/SCSS?

Comment: I also thought about css preprocessors but in my case, I have to update it runtime whereas sass -> css happens compile time.

Comment: change the style in head, http://ewoutreinders.com/index.php/angular-2-changing-stylesheets-in-the-tag-runtime/

Comment: idk what's wrong with ng-style - i would definetely prefere it to inline styles

Comment: there is nothing wrong with ng-style. But in my case, there are 1000 places to apply ng-style. Hence it is not feasible for me.

Comment: @Eliseo - I have read that post. The example has predefined theme file created and in my case my user changes theme file on runtime. [theme.css is generated by the backend code on every save theme action].

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<div [style.background-color]="yourVar"></div>
```

In this case the binding should work

Comment: Good idea and I think this will work for many cases. But what if someone wants to set a style on a pseudo-element? Also the OP mentioned (and dismissed) ngStyle.

Comment: ok but there are many elements to style. It is exhaustive to add styles to around 1000 elements.

Answer (score 2):

There's no pretty way to do this without building a huge structure like Angular Material does. But, if your theme system is not so complex, I'd simply go with a dynamically rendering of the `<link>` tag to your theme like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <link rel="stylesheet" [href]="getThemeUrl()">
    <div class="main">
        {{'themes/css/'+ theme +'.css' }}

        <select [(ngModel)]="theme" (change)="onThemeChanged(theme)">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    theme = 'red';

    constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    getThemeUrl(){
        return this.sanitizer
            .bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('themes/' + this.theme + '.css');
    }
}
```

[Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/lsi1VPHFaLSEoZraQcAF?p=preview)

Comment: It works perfectly, but only one problem with this is that the css file is re-requested on every UI interaction. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Ashwin maybe if you use `[href]="'/themes/css/' + theme + '.min.css'"`

Comment: Having a problem with running your problem. It keep on saying "Loading...". as soon as I fix it I will update you.

Comment: @Ashwin anyways there's a plunkr with a working solution https://embed.plnkr.co/lsi1VPHFaLSEoZraQcAF?p=preview it's a version mismatch try to compare angular's version in the `system.config.js` file.

Comment: I checked your plunkr and I am seeing one problem which I mentioned in my first comment i.e. when I have something else updating (like a variable interpolating) then the css file is requested again, if you could see that in Network tab. This gives a flickering UI on the screen.

https://plnkr.co/edit/nV4WOR9efThiRs1V3gCK?p=preview